# bash completion using ls

Tags: bash, scripts

This works from shell:

```
 export files=`ls /home/tests/`
 complete -o filenames -W "${files}" xtest
```

This script doesn't :

```
 _xtest ()   {                .
      local cur
      local files=`ls /home/tests`
      COMPREPLY=()     cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

      #case "$cur" in

        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) )
    #  esac
      return 0
    }

    complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```

What is the way using  a script for autocomplete from file list of a directory ?
I'm using a script because only for 1 script option (-test) is this customized autocomplete required, for other script options (-speed, -define) default autocomplete is O.K.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable and assigning it on one line can mask the return values. The use of `$(..)` instead of legacy backticks is prefered. Given the lack of context of your code snippit the folowing code is the best I can do with out being able to test it.

```
 _xtest ()   {
      local cur
      local files
      files=$(ls /home/tests)
      COMPREPLY=()
      cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

      case "$cur" in
      -*)
      COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W $files --$cur ) );;
      esac
      return 0
    }

    complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```